# Netbeans, get file properties from res folder

Tags: java, netbeans, resources

I´m trying to get a property file from res folder but I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name res/Interfaz, locale es_ES
```

This is the project tree:

[image]

And this is my simple code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("res/Interfaz", Locale.getDefault());
    //String name = rb.getString("name");
    //System.out.println(name);   // Si el idioma del sistema es español, imprime "Nombre".
    
  
    }

}
```

I´m using Netbeans 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the solution. As my project is a Maven project, following Maven conventions, I hace to create a new resources folder in the src/main/ directory of the project. This src/main/resources path will automatically be marked as a resource directory next time I build the project using Maven.

And from code I access it as:

```
 ResourceBundle.getBundle("Interfaz", Locale.getDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

MyMaven\src\main

- resources
- java

code:
`ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("hcenterMod");`
[image]